# Facebook not crawling for share - cURL error?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, curl, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I don't know if this is the right place to go, but I am at a loss as to what to do.

I have a hosted Wordpress site and I suddenly (a few days ago) began having trouble with Facebook being unable to crawl the site correctly when sharing a post.

My SEO plug-in Support blamed my hosting provider, and it's true that open graph OG tags seem to be fine (according to page source).

The Sharing Debugger is giving a cURL error, either...

```
Curl error: 35 (SSL_CONNECT_ERROR)
```

or...

```
Curl error: 56 (RECV_ERROR)
```

My hosting provider Support claims they can't update cURL and blames Facebook for the error. They say I should "contact Facebook" but I don't know where to begin for that.

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As noted in original post, this started a few days ago. These three posts are new since then: [Post 1](https://www.thebozho.com/langhorne-slim-runnin-down-dream/), [Post 2](https://www.thebozho.com/tammy-baldwin-seth-meyers-spotted-cow/) and [Post 3](https://www.thebozho.com/nba-draft-pick-number-seventeen/)

Comment: I checked your domain using ssllabs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.thebozho.com . It also had problem connecting. So something is wrong with your hosting provider

Comment: Thank you. I just clicked your link and it seemed to connect without issue and displays an "overall rating A".

Comment: When I clicked it didn't work. So I guess your hosting provider sometimes work

Comment: Time to get a new hosting provider. Thanks again.